# RESTful address for image list

Tags: html, api, http, rest

I've looked at many SO answers about REST, but the concept is still not clear.
At least, it seemed to me naming(the URL) properly is central to what REST is.

How do I make my address scheme below restful?
(I have list of images, but for each request I present different subset of them)

```
image_list/recent      (all image sorted in descending)
image_list/recent/front/  (to request newer images than a client has. client will provide the latest image id he has) 

image_list/popular (sorted in popularity)
image_list/following/ (list of images of users that a client follows)
image_list/user_like/  (list of images a client likes)
```

how about when you have many operations that you can perform on a resource?

```
image/upload/
image/delete/
image/like/
image/dislike/
image/hide/
```

*EDIT*

This is the solution after looking at answers. 
(But I still have doubts and did indicate so)

First set

```
images/?mode=recent
images/?mode=recent_front
images/?mode=popular
images/?mode=following&user_id=3
images/?mode=like&user_id=3
```

Isn't it a convention to use `images/ for all images` even though the `all images set` keeps changing?
Why can't I just use `images/recent` then?

Second set

```
images/ POST  (to create)
images/ DELETE 
 (to delete, ok but I have not seen anyone using `DELETE`. Does anyone use it?)
images/3/like POST (OK there's a `like` DB entity)
images/3/dislike POST (umm but there's no dislike DB entity)
images/3/hide .. (there's no hide entity, it's a merely a field on image)
```

Comment: your resource is image period , the rest should be in the query sting like /image?&sort=recent&user_like=true&following=false

Comment: updated my answer based on edits and HIDE options

Comment: @Eugene because in images/recent recent is not a resource itself its a form of images resource-collection . recent is more of a filter

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you know, REST is much more than a naming scheme for URLs.

What's important with your URI naming scheme is that the URI uniquely identifies a particular resource/entity. Quoting directly from the Wiki page:

> An important concept in REST is the existence of resources (sources of
>   specific information), each of which is referenced with a global
>   identifier (e.g., a URI in HTTP).

In your case, you want your URIs to structured so that they can uniquely identify an image or the collection of all images as a whole. There is more than one way to do this. Some people prefer query strings and others (including myself) prefer including identifiers as part of the URI folder structure. REST doesn't dictate one or the other.

Think about what you need to identify an image--it could be a filename, but if your application is database driven, it's more likely you'd be using an index ID number. You could setup your URI as such:

```
http://YOURDOMAIN.TLD/API/IMAGE/232423
```

Where `232423` uniquely identifies the image.

Now on to your second question:

> how about when you have many operations that you can perform on a resource?

With REST APIs over HTTP, the action is typically specified by the HTTP method you utilize. `GET` for retrieving data, `POST` for updating/inserting data and `DELETE` for deleting data. It's not common practice to have the URI itself specify the action--as you've done above. Please note, that I'm talking about what's *common practice*--the principles of REST don't dictate what HTTP methods should be used or the URI naming structure.

Taking your example of likes on an image, you should treat the likes on the page as a resource--a unique entity. There are different actions that you want to do with this entity such as: 1. look up the number of likes on an image, 2. add a new like to the total.

For your REST method to *like* an image, you could set it up as a `POST` to a URI like this:

```
http://YOURDOMAIN.TLD/API/IMAGE/232423/LIKE
```

Where `232423` is an identifier for the image and `LIKE` refers to the likes on that particular image.

If you wanted to retrieve the number of likes on the image, use the same URI, but switch the HTTP method to `GET`.

Comment: One hint there's a REST problem if there's a verb in the url (LIKE)

Comment: A 'like' can be both and noun and a verb (I'm not talking about what the English dictionary says). You can like something (verb) or something can have 'likes' (noun). Conceptually, the key with REST is that you essentially use nouns with identifiers in the URI.

Comment: Here it is being used as a verb - to LIKE an image.

Comment: If you POST a VOTE resource then it's a noun/resource

Comment: If your objection is to whether I should include an S at the end of `LIKE`, then our disagreement is purely semantic. I prefer not to use the S in the same way a database table of cats might be called CAT instead of CATS.

Comment: My point is that when you LIKE an image, you are actually applying a VOTE (resource) against the image.  The VOTE is a temporal RESOURCE being applied (POST) to the image.  Very similar to the transaction temporaral resource in: http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-07-03-nobody-understands-rest-or-http